# Display database in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem when I try changeable search

- I have one combobox who's items change a text in textbox2
- TextBox2.text is the names of the tables

Code:

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name,Phone from '"+textBox2.Text+"' where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' ", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SDA.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    textBox3.Text = (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
}
```

When I am using fixed name for the table it is working fine.

For example

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name,Phone from Table where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' ", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SDA.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    textBox3.Text = (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You placed extra `'`:

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name,Phone from "+textBox2.Text+" where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' ", con);
```

Comment: Thanks  such a small mistake cost me 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `'` signal  quotes on the `From` table.

```
"Select Name,Phone from "+textBox2.Text+" where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' "
```

Instead of

```
"Select Name,Phone from '"+textBox2.Text+"' where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' "
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this does the job

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code snippet . it should work for you. There is extra  ' in your select

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Name,Phone from "+textBox2.Text+"' where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            textBox3.Text = (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }
```